# Flink: how to join/group 2 streams by key?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 2 streams of events, where one is the result of a `flatmap`.  I want to join all events that share a common identifier.

Thus I have something that looks like:

```
DataStream<TypeA> streamA = ...
DataStream<TypeB> streamB = someDataStream.flatMap(...) // produces stream of TypeB for each item in someDataStream
```

Both `TypeA` and `TypeB` share an identifier and I know how many `TypeB` objects there are in the parent object.  I want to perform some processing when all of the events associated with a particular identifier have arrived, i.e. when I basically can create a `Tuple3<id, TypeA, List<TypeB>>` object.

Is this best done with a `WindowJoin` and a `GlobalWindow`, a `Window CoGroup` and a `GlobalWindow` or by connecting the 2 streams into a `ConnectedStream` then performing the joining inside a `CoProcessFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

Windows are the way Flink simulates Batching, think it's not what you are searching for.

Just make something like

```
streamA.keyBy(element.getFieldToKey).connect(streamB.keyBy(element.getFieldToKey))
```

Then you can apply a CoProcess or a CoFlatMap function where your IN1 is StreamA type and IN2 is StreamB type. OUT is your result type.